# Is it possible to check the Connected RPC network in MetaMask using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, binance-smart-chain

In my DApp, I want to check whether the MetaMask in connected to BSC Minnet RPC network using JQuery. Is it possible to check the Connected RPC network in MetaMask using JQuery?

Thanks a bunch in advance!!

Comment: JQuery can do two things really: 1. Affect the DOM (the current web page) 2. Call a web service. If whatever on earth it is that you're trying to do can be acheived by calling a web service, then yes. But I wouldn't bother with JQuery, use the newer native javascript `fetch`

Answer (score 0):

MetaMask implements the Ethereum Provider API, so you can read the `chainId` property ([docs](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/ethereum-provider.html#chain-ids)).

```
if (window?.ethereum?.chainId === "0x38") {
    console.log("currently selected BSC mainnet");
}
```